# Usage of the article 'the' in the phrase Internet of Things

Tags: grammar, articles

I am writing a paper on the topic, Internet of Things as a part of my curriculum. I couldn't help but wonder as to why every article, conference paper and journal publication refers to it as  "***The*** *Internet of Things* ". If my memory serves the is added to a noun (common noun) or a phrase if it weren't specific (or precise) enough. There are cases wherein proper nouns also take the article 'the' like names of geographical locations such as rivers, oceans, mountain ranges etc. However I don't see a need for using 'the' in this context. The name of the topic in itself is precise enough and leads to no confusion of subject after all.

**I know there is a question about usage of articles properly, that has been answered. However, it doesn't answer my question accurately. So I implore the readers to not jump the gun and mark this question as duplicate.**
*References:*

1. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_of_Things)
2. [Cisco](http://www.cisco.com/web/solutions/trends/iot/overview.html)
3. [Techopedia](http://www.techopedia.com/definition/28247/internet-of-things-iot)
4. [Tech-target](http://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/Internet-of-Things)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what the subject actually is (it's your paper), but I can imagine "the internet of things" as a phrase describing a particular aspect of the internet that you might be writing about. You could have "The internet of people", "the internet of rumour", "the internet of conspiracy theories".

Other parallel examples: "The Cornwall of my childhood", "The cinema of shock", "The politics of class".

Comment: That makes sense.

Comment: I know this is off the topic but I can't possibly think a reason for your choice of username. You chose the name of one of the two muses who has nothing to do with literature.  Not that it's any of my business but would you care to tell me the reason for your choice?

Comment: @manu It sounded nice. Or it does if you pronounce it properly: Terpsickory. There is no other reason. I have no interest in dancing. (By the same logic, I can't assume you have any interest in football.)

Comment: Ha ha ha. Manu doesn't stand for Manchester United here. It's my pet name, a shorter version of my name Manohar. And I don't expect you to have a logical reason for your name.

Comment: @manu Pity. I was hoping to congratulate you on yesterday's win.